# How to populate data outcome from multiple criteria within selecting rows

Tags: t-sql, subquery

I am trying to select distinct rows of data from a table (in general), but also within the same select statement, I would like to select distinct rows based on **multiple criteria** using the same table.

[image]

-- logic is:

-- select distinct rows from a table

-- but when there are rows that have the same on all these 7 fields:

-- batch_no, batch_date, accountno, locationid, amount, depid, glenkey

-- Then, select the row that has the *later* **whencreated** column data.

```
-- This is query for sample data
select * 
into #temp
from 
(values 
(56555,  '2022-04-01',  48570,  111, 445.00, 217, 1877885, '2022-03-01'),
(45698,  '2022-03-01',  62550,  110, 344.59, 216, 1910945, '2022-02-01'),
(45698,  '2022-03-01',  62550,  110, 344.59, 216, 1910945, '2022-01-01')
)
t1
(batch_no, batch_date, accountno, locationid, amount, deptid, glenkey, whencreated)


-- logic is:
-- select distinct rows
-- but when there are rows that have the same on all these 7 fields: 
-- batch_no, batch_date, accountno, locationid, amount, depid, glenkey
-- then, select the row that has the later whencreated column data. 


select distinct batch_no, batch_date, accountno, locationid, amount, deptid, glenkey, 
whencreated from #temp


-- Expected outcome (manually created to be used for you):
select * 
INTO #temp1
from 
(values 
(56555,  '2022-04-01',  48570,  111, 445.00, 217, 1877885, '2022-03-01'),
(45698,  '2022-03-01',  62550,  110, 344.59, 216, 1910945, '2022-02-01')
)
t1
(batch_no, batch_date, accountno, locationid, amount, deptid, glenkey, whencreated)
```

Expected output:

[image]

Do I need to use subquery? How do I write in T-SQL?

Comment: Maybe select first7columns, max(whencreated) from table group by first7columns?

Comment: @jigga How do I combine to populate with other regular ones (without grouping ones)? Can you please show me the T-SQL? Thanks.

Comment: Grouping unique data is the same as showing it... Try and you will see... For the tsql just replace the word first7columns with your 7 columns and run it